# "Server refused our key" - After creating a new instance using private AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, putty

I needed to upgrade my instance type, so I created an AMI from my t2.micro in us-east-1a.

I then created a new instance based on the above AMI to a t2.medium in us-east-1d.

Both have the exact same Key Name.

Both have the exact same Security Group.

Both are in the exact same VPC.

This is a web server, and the server is running fine as such.

Yet, now when I attempt to login via PuTTY, I get an error "Server refused our key".

I'm using the same Saved Session inside PuTTY and using the same PPK file and login details.

Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: What type of Linux? What username?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - why is it off-topic? i saw lots of similar (not relevant to my situation exactly) questions here, and also tons of posts related to my tags on SO - when i checked SU there are almost none...

Comment: @RodrigoM - this is amazon linux on the EC2 platform, username is "ec2-user"

Comment: The sad fact that there are tons of off-topic questions on Stack Overflow does not justify you posting yet another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upgrade your instance from t2.micro to t2.medium then you don't have to create an AMI for the same. You can do the same without creating an AMI. You need to stop your Instance and just go to Action -> Instance Setting -> Change Instance Type. From where you can upgrade or downgrade your Instance directly. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxR2t.png)